# Spark context keeps stopping when trying to start a stream that is subscribed to an instance of cloud karafka

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to subcribe to a kafka topic that's located in the cloud(CloudKarafka). I want to write my stream to the console to test if I'm consuming the messages. However when I start my writestream it just keeps stopping my sparkcontext. I'm not sure if the connection is my problem or my code is the problem.

I have consumed from this topic before with Apache Flink and then it was working fine. One thing I noticed is that when I was connecting with Flink instead of Spark I would use the option("bootstrap.servers",...) instead of the mandatory ("kafka.bootstrap.servers",...) does this have something to do with it?

My service:

```
private static SparkSession spark;
public SparkService( SparkSession sparkSes) {

       spark  = sparkSes;


    }
 public void ConsumeSpark(){

Dataset<Row> dataset = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
                .option("sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-256")
                .option("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=name password=pw;")
                .option("group.id","name-spark")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",brokers)
                .option("subscribe","name-default")
                .load();

        dataset.writeStream().format("console").outputMode("append").start();
}
```

Main:

```
SparkService s = new SparkService( SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("pleasework")
                .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
                .getOrCreate());
```

I expect that my records when they get consumed just get printed in the console.
Instead it stops my spark context.
Logs:

```
19/08/17 12:12:36 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Starting [id = 86b7262c-f316-461b-abcc-3fb8e639d597, runId = 4881453b-530a-4093-a535-7528e86243ab]. Use file:/C:/Users/Sam/IdeaProjects/spark/checkpoints to store the query checkpoint.
19/08/17 12:12:36 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
19/08/17 12:12:36 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Using MicroBatchReader [KafkaV2[Subscribe[name-default]]] from DataSourceV2 named 'kafka' [org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider@2ffca6f]
19/08/17 12:12:36 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 86b7262c-f316-461b-abcc-3fb8e639d597, runId = 4881453b-530a-4093-a535-7528e86243ab] terminated with error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
Main.main(Main.java:9)

The currently active SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
Main.main(Main.java:9)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.<init>(SparkSession.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.cloneSession(SparkSession.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
```

Thanks in advance for looking at this!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add "kafka." before all my options otherwise it won't change the consumerConfiguration

```
.option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
```

Also didn't wrote the await termination

```
spark.streams().awaitAnyTermination();
```